# Kendo Grid Client Template input validation

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid, kendo-validator

I'm currently building a grid that goes against the general way Progress mean to use their Grid but I'm hoping this is possible (I'm currently stumped).

The requirement is simple enough: show input field(s) in the client template of the grid across all rows.
When clicking on a command button - ensure the input field(s) are valid before continuing.

Any which way I try the below instance, the kendo validator will not recognise either the data source schema's model field validation, OR any attributes on the input field(s) themselves.
Ultimately I want to get the `pattern`/`data-val-regex` HTML5/unobtrusive validation working.

Any help would be appreciated.

The Grid I have is coded as;

```
$(function() {
    var Data = [];
    jQuery("#grdData").kendoGrid({
        "dataBound": grdData_Bound,
        "editable": "inline",
        "columns": [{
            "title": "Id",
            "field": "Id",
            "template": "#=FieldValueEditor(data, \"HiddenField\", \"Id\", \"\")#",
            "hidden": true
        }, {
            "title": "Name",
            "field": "Name",
            "template": "#=FieldValueEditor(data, \"TextField\", \"Name\", \".+\")#"
        }, {
            "title": "Description",
            "field": "Description"
        }, {
            "title": "Requirements",
            "field": "Requirements"
        }, {
            "title": "Icon",
            "field": "Icon"
        }, {
            "title": "Type",
            "field": "Type"
        }, {
            "title": "ActionText",
            "field": "ActionText"
        }, {
            "title": "ActionWarning",
            "field": "ActionWarning"
        }, {
            "title": "Timeout",
            "field": "Timeout"
        }, {
            "title": "Retention",
            "field": "Retention"
        }, {
            "title": "Active",
            "field": "Active"
        }, {
            "title": "New Requirements",
            "field": "NewRequirements",
            "template": "#=FieldValueEditor(data, \"TextField\", \"NewRequirements\", \".+\")#"
        }, {
            "title": "",
            "field": "Commands",
            "command": [{
                "text": "Save Requirements",
                "name": "SaveRequirements",
                "click": grdData_Command
            }, {
                "text": "Save Name",
                "name": "SaveName",
                "click": grdData_Command
            }, ]
        }, ],
        "dataSource": {
            "type": (function() {
                if (kendo.data.transports['aspnetmvc-ajax']) {
                    return 'aspnetmvc-ajax';
                } else {
                    throw new Error('The kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js script is not included.');
                }
            }
            )(),
            "transport": {
                "read": {
                    "url": "/Action/View/1/62/Data",
                    "data": AntiForgeryToken
                }
            },
            "pageSize": 4,
            "schema": {
                "data": "Data",
                "total": "Total",
                "errors": "Errors",
                "model": {
                    "id": "Name",
                    "fields": {
                        "Id": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "validation": {
                                "required": true,
                                "pattern": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "Name": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "validation": {
                                "required": true,
                                "pattern": ".+"
                            }
                        },
                        "Description": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "validation": {
                                "required": true,
                                "pattern": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "Requirements": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "validation": {
                                "required": true,
                                "pattern": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "Icon": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "validation": {
                                "required": true,
                                "pattern": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "Type": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "validation": {
                                "required": true,
                                "pattern": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "ActionText": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "validation": {
                                "required": true,
                                "pattern": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "ActionWarning": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "validation": {
                                "required": true,
                                "pattern": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "Timeout": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "validation": {
                                "required": true,
                                "pattern": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "Retention": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "validation": {
                                "required": true,
                                "pattern": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "Active": {
                            "type": "boolean",
                            "validation": {
                                "required": true,
                                "pattern": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "NewRequirements": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "validation": {
                                "required": true,
                                "pattern": ".+"
                            }
                        },
                        "Commands": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "validation": {
                                "required": true,
                                "pattern": ""
                            }
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

With this Grid, for certain cells, it calls the `FieldValueEditor` method to grab the Client Template;

```
function FieldValueEditor(data, fieldType, columnName, validationExpression) {
    var wrapper = {
        ColumnName: columnName,
        ValidationExpression: validationExpression,
        Data: data
    };
    var raw = $(`#${fieldType}-editor`).html();
    var proxy = kendo.template(raw);
    var html = proxy(wrapper);
    return html;
}
```

This in turn, renders one of the following script templates depending on the field type;

```
<script type="text/html" id="HiddenField-editor">
    <input type="hidden" class="hidden-field" data-bind="value:#:ColumnName#" />
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="TextField-editor">                
    <input type="text" class="text-field" data-bind="value:#:ColumnName#" />
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="DateField-editor">
    <input type="date" class="date-field" data-bind="value:#:ColumnName#" />
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="CheckField-editor">            
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-field" data-bind="value:#:ColumnName#"/>
</script>
```

Additionally, I do have some `dataBound` logic, ensuring the data item(s) are bound to each row;

```
 function grdData_Bound(e) {
    jQuery(".text-field").kendoTextBox({});
    jQuery(".date-field").kendoDatePicker({});
    $grid = $("#grdData");
    var grid = $grid.data("kendoGrid");
    $grid.find('tr.k-master-row').each(function() {
        var $row = $(this);
        $row.kendoValidator().data('kendoValidator');
        var model = grid.dataItem($row);
        kendo.bind($row, model);
    });
    $grid.focus();
}
```

When activating either of the two command buttons `Save Name` or `Save Requirements`, the validator from `$row` returns true when calling `validate`

```
  function grdData_Command(e) {
                var $row = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.k-master-row');
                var validator = $row.data('kendoValidator');
                if (validator.validate()) {
                    //always goes in here, no matter how I setup the validation
               } else {
                   //never goes in here
              }
 }
```

Comment: Please be aware that the "jQuery validator" referenced in the Kendo documentation is not the same as the jQuery Validate plugin you had tagged here.  Edited tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a stupid mistake on my part.
In short, I was unaware that the `pattern` attribute does not get triggered by the `kendoValidator.validate` method if the field is empty. When using an empty field it appears you **must** use required; which ultimately makes sense and gives you the option of having an optional but strict regular expression.

The fix was to pass in required/pattern pattern parameters to the client template like so -

```
<script type="text/html" id="TextField-editor">
    <input type="text" class="text-field" data-bind="value:#:ColumnName#" #if(Required){# required#}##if(Pattern){# pattern="#=Pattern#" #}# validationMessage="Please enter a valid value" />
</script>
```

..and it simply works!